# How to configure a network in Ubuntu 20.04 when the network directory does not exists?

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am using [this](https://wiki.t-firefly.com/en/ROC-RK3328-PC/linux_build_rootfilesystem.html) tutorial to configure the rootfs for ubuntu 20.04, I realize that this distro does not have the network directory but it is created after I use this command from the tutorial I mentioned before:

```
apt-get install ifupdown
```

but in [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-switch-back-networking-to-etc-network-interfaces-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) article I read:

"WARNING
Switching back from NetPlan/CloudInit to the now obsolete networking daemon is not supported nor recommended as you might end up with a broken system."

My internet connection works ok after the steps in the tutorial + using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure network-manager` but I don´t know if this is the correct way to achieve the network config

Comment: It is never the correct way to use old tutorials that are no longer applicable.

Comment: The OP is installing Ubuntu Base onto a device. That means copying a .img (with a root filesystem) instead of using a LiveUSB installer. This is a sensible question for that rather advanced use case. The answer is that the tutorial is a bit stale, and that particular line has been superseded. Check if the `netplan.io` package is installed; if not, install it (`apt-get install netplan.io`). Then check the /etc/netplan directory for a YAML file. Edit the file as needed to set up your next-reboot connection settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 uses netplan https://netplan.io/

All your configuration is in file:
/etc/netplan/2020 01-network-manager-all.yaml

Comment: ...and don't forget to use `netplan generate` to test the YAML.